# array of objects initialization compiler error

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class pes{
   public static void main(String args[]){

      Computer[] c=new Computer[3];

      Computer c[0]= new Computer("Jayu",66,10,20,30,40,50);

      for(int i=0;i<3;i++){
         c[i].d();
      }  
   }

}
```

I am getting ']' expected pointing at 0 and illegal start of expression pointing at ']' bracket before equals to sign..!!

Answer (score 2):

This is invalid syntax

```
Computer c[0]= new Computer("Jayu",66,10,20,30,40,50);
```

Change it to

```
c[0] = new Computer("Jayu",66,10,20,30,40,50);
```

Answer (score 1):

The `Computer` part in your assignment is invalid - you're trying to declare anything. It should just be:

```
c[0] = new Computer(...);
```

At that point it will compile - but you'll get a `NullPointerException` when `i` is 1. You'll need to either check whether `c[i]` is null before dereferencing it, or make sure you popuate the whole array rather than just the first element.